# Enable Large Text through Terminal

Tags: command-line, nvidia, gui, text, accessibility

I need to know how to enable and disable Large Text accessibility feature through the Ubuntu 20.04 Terminal.

My desktop is constantly in large text mode (even though the accessibility settings don't say so) due to some Nvidia driver issues.  The workaround that I've found, is to enable and disable Large Text Mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the Text scaling factor using gsettings from a terminal.  To scale to 125%:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.25
```

To reset to standard size:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.0
```

These changes effectively toggle the 'Large text' switch in `Settings > Universal Access`.